# Inner/Outer (Inside/Outside) margin in Pages

Tags: pages, formatting

Is there any way to set inner/ outer margin in Pages? I'm going to print my thesis both side and as I can see in the Document tab under `Document Margins` there is only Left and Right margin. If it's the only setting how can I achieve it? I've got more than 60 pages in my document.

Comment: Do you think that if you set to print double-sided then Pages will put the left margin on the left of each sheet etc Why not do a test print of 3 or 4 pages and see...

Comment: @Tetsujin When you print document like a book then it makes a difference. If you set left/right than every page will be the same but for inner/outer you can have more space where pages are connected

Comment: @SolarMike I checked and it doesn't affect the margins

Comment: It looks like the option to have inner/outer margins was removed after Pages v4.3: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6798627

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was fixed in newer version of Pages. When I asked this question more than 2 years ago I switched to Word because I couldn't make this work.

Solution in Pages 10.0 (6748):

Go to `Document` Settings and under `Document Margins` select `Facing Pages`. Now Left/Right margin will change to Inside/Outside. Result of setting inside to 2cm and outside to 5cm:

[image]